# I have never understood a word Alice "has said" or "said"

Tags: differences, past-tense, present-perfect

I am not sure about the use of present perfect in the subordinate clause. *I want to say I've never understood Alice for as long as I've known her*, so should I use the present perfect aspect in the subordinate clause or the past tense?

> I have never understood a word that Alice **has said**.

or

> I have never understood a word that Alice **said**.

To me, the first sentence sounds like *I* haven't understood what Alice has *just* said.

Comment: How about *I can't understand a word she says.* This keeps it in the present while encapsulating the past at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I should say:

> I have never understood a word *of what* Alice has said.

meaning I never understood **any** of the words.

otherwise John might say: *I never understood a word that Alice has said.* and Paul might reply: *Oh? What word was that?*

Alternatively, if I no longer speak to her

> I never understood a word *of what* Alice said.

Comment: Why would you say that in preference to the OP's phrasing, and why does your second sentence imply that you no longer speak to Alice?

Comment: Unless I limit the use of 'never' with a word such as *until* it will include the present. Thus I currently don't understand anything she **said**. Following through to conclusion: in the present her speech is in the past, hence, I no longer speak to Alice. If I still speak to her, I would've said: "I never understand a word of what Alice says" or "I never understood a word of what Alice said until I walked a mile in her shoes"

Comment: *Unless **I** limit* Is this more than an idiosyncrasy of yours?  And if so, do you have a source to support this claim?  Because I don't think "Have never" includes the present.  You could be standing next to Alice and say "I have never understood a word that Alice has said."  Which would include her last remark but not necessarily her next.

Comment: Trolls will be trolls. You clearly agree with me: "..would include her last remark, but not necessarily her next". The only questions are whether you understand what I meant and whether you know time. Her next remark is in the future. I never said "have never" included the future.

Comment: I don't agree with you.   In my example, Alice is standing right there, where you're still talking to her.  You think I'm trolling?  I'm done with you.

Answer (score 0):

1) I have never understood [unspecified past at this moment of speaking on the timeline] a word Alice has said [unspecified past at this moment of speaking on the timeline]: at this moment of speaking, on the timeline.

VERSUS: 2) I have never understood [unspecified past at this moment of speaking on the timeline] a word Alice said [simple present implies at a particular time].

in 2) at the time of speaking in the present, I have not understood what Alice said [at a specific moment in time]. She said something at some particular time (last week, in October, last year) and I still do not understand it today.

Both are correct, it all depends on what the speaker means: what Alice said [that time, yesterday etc.=a specific moment in time] versus in a past that it not specified at the time of speaking: Alice has said.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I want to say that I've never understood her, the first is more on point?

Comment: If there's a semantic difference between the two phrasings, I can't see it.  The present perfect covers past time up to the present.  The simple past generally records a specific time, but the *never* means that for all specific times in the past, I have failed to understand Alice.  So the lack of understanding covers the same points on the timeline of listening to Alice.

Comment: Let me give you another example then: I have never liked what he said [on some day]. I have never liked what he has said [in the past, not specified.] Same here.. The difference is not semantic; the verbs make the two sentences mean something different. I have never understood [in the present, and I am still thinking about it, what Alice said [one time in the past. VERSUS I have never understood [in the present and am still thinking about it] what Alice said [at the party]. And keep  your minuses to yourselves until you understand verb tenses in English.

Answer (score 0):

**I have never understood a word of what Alice has said.** 
this will be the correct form of sentence.